# What would be the best way to conduct this query in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, search

I am working on my first project in laravel and now I perform the search functionality, however, I am doing a query which involves several left join and when searching returns me a bit redundant information.

The related tables are these four, and the query is as follows:

[image: demo]

```
$searchData = ProfessionalDetail::select('u.id as user_id','u.first_name','u.last_name','u.profile_pic','c.name as city_name','professional_details.avg_ratings')
    ->join('users as u' , 'u.id', '=' ,'professional_details.user_id')
    ->join('user_speciality as us' , 'us.user_id', '=' ,'professional_details.user_id')
    ->join('specialities as sp' , 'sp.id', '=' ,'us.speciality_id')
    ->join('cities as c' , 'c.id', '=' ,'professional_details.city_id')
    ->join('users_roles as ur' , 'ur.user_id', '=' ,'professional_details.user_id')
    ->where( function ( $q2 ) use ( $name) {
         $q2->where('u.first_name' , 'like', '%' . $name . '%')
         ->orWhere('u.last_name','like', '%'.$name.'%')
         ->orWhere('u.first_name','like',$name.'%');
         ->orWhere('sp.name','like',$name.'%');
    })
    ->where('ur.role_id' ,'=' , 2)
    ->paginate($num_per_page);

    return $searchData;[![demo][1]][1]
```

What I tried, is that users are listed, by name or by specialty (it is a doctors page), when ready by specialty everything is going well. But when I want to list by users, having the left join 'user_speciality' and 'professional_details'. This returns me the user numerous times.

For example:

```
public function testApi(Request $request)
{
    $users = ProfessionalDetail::searchByNameAndSpe("joshi", 10);
    $i = 0;
    if ($users) {
        foreach ($users as $key => $value) {
            $response["result"][] = $value;
            $response["total"] = $i++;
        }

    } else {
        return "error";
    }

    return $response;
}
```

Returns:

```
{"result":[{"user_id":204,"first_name":"Joshi","last_name":"Mohit","profile_pic":"1495436016.jpg","name":"Skin Specialist","city_name":"Pune","avg_ratings":"0.00"},{"user_id":204,"first_name":"Joshi","last_name":"Mohit","profile_pic":"1495436016.jpg","name":"Heart Specialist","city_name":"Pune","avg_ratings":"0.00"},{"user_id":204,"first_name":"Joshi","last_name":"Mohit","profile_pic":"1495436016.jpg","name":"ENT Specialist","city_name":"Pune","avg_ratings":"0.00"},{"user_id":204,"first_name":"Joshi","last_name":"Mohit","profile_pic":"1495436016.jpg","name":"Kidney Specialist","city_name":"Pune","avg_ratings":"0.00"},{"user_id":204,"first_name":"Joshi","last_name":"Mohit","profile_pic":"1495436016.jpg","name":"Eye Specialist","city_name":"Pune","avg_ratings":"0.00"}],"total":4}
```

Joshi is only registered once, however I know that he will be returned numerous times due to the relation 'many to many' since he owns several specialties.

[image: demo]

Now, to get it to search by specialty and the name of the users, the only way I know is to use the left join, I think a way to separate the information would be handling the information of the array in the controller, however I I would like to know if this can be resolved in the query, since I do not know much about SQL, if there is any way I would be very grateful as it would save me many steps to debug all the information.

The methods of each model

UserSpeciality table

```
public function users() {

    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'user_speciality', 'speciality_id', 'user_id');
}
```

User

```
  public function userSpeciality() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Speciality','user_speciality', 'user_id', 'speciality_id');
}
```

speciality

```
public function users() {

    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'user_speciality', 'user_id', 'speciality_id');
}
```

ProfesionalDetail table

```
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo("App\User");
    }
```

Comment: Do you have models set up for these tables?

Comment: If and each one has its corresponding method for the relation, 
I have modified the post and added them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have try once group by user id

groupBy(user_id)